# Can I use require to import a full JS file in ES6 module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently, I've supporting a Laravel project that uses Laravel Mix as front-end asset bundler (CSS and JS). I've noticed that, in main JS file, the developer was used some `require()` rules at start, and those `require()` rules was referring to other JS files located in same directory, and those JS files are "normal" browser-friendly JS script (like jQuery, Bootstrap, GSAP etc). After those `require()` rules, the developer used normal `import` rules from ES6, referring to NodeJS dependencies and other modules within the project.

To better explain what I'm trying to show...

File tree:

```
.
└── src
    ├── bootstrap.js
    ├── components
    │   ├── AnotherFeature.js
    │   ├── Carousel.js
    │   └── Something.js
    ├── jquery.js
    └── main.js
```

The `main.js` file...

```js
require("jquery");
require("bootstrap");

import {AnotherFeature} from "./components/AnotherFeature";
import {Carousel} from "./components/Carousel";
import {Something} from "./components/Something";

class Main {
    constructor() {
        new AnotherFeature();
        new Carousel();
        new Something();
    }
}
new Main();
```

And, even using Laravel Mix (that uses Webpack), the `jQuery`, `$` and `bootstrap` are available to run through browser`s console.

My question is: how can I do something like this outside Laravel Mix? I'm working on a project that uses JS, and some third-party resources aren`t ES6 modules, and I can't find a beautiful solution to use them in my project. The way Laravel Mix "import" extra JS files is a good way to fix my issues, keeping simple and all thing in one bundled JS file.

You can find my project at my [GitHub](https://github.com/RBFraphael/wp-starter-theme). It consists in a Wordpress starter template that people want to use at my job, and this method of "requiring" and "importing" things will be very helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: "*how can I do something like this?*" - you really shouldn't. Always use `import` declarations. Then configure your build toolchain (esp. the bundler) to resolve these modules correctly, even if they are standalone scripts not modules.

Comment: Why is this tagged [[tag:node.js]]? This looks very much like a frontend project.